# How do I prove two definitions of the variation of a measure are equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space and $\mu:\Sigma\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a complex measure.

Define $|\mu|(E)$ as the supremum of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |\mu(E_n)|$ where $\{E_n\}$ is a mutually disjoint sequence in $\Sigma$ such that $\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty E_n=E$, for all $E\in\Sigma$.

Define $\mu_A(E)$ as the supremum of $\sum_{n=0}^N |\mu(E_n)|$ where $\{E_n\}_{0\leq n\leq N}$ is a mutually disjoint **finite** sequence in $\Sigma$ whose union is $E$, for all $E\in\Sigma$.

How do I prove that $|\mu|=\mu_A$?

Of course, $\mu_A \leq |\mu|$. However, I am not sure about the converse. (I do not even know whether this is true, but I think this would be true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{E_n\}$ be a partition of a measurable set $E$ (i.e. a countable mutually disjoint collection whose union is $E$).  then for $m\in\mathbb{N}$, the collection $\{E_1,\ldots,E_m,\bigcup_{n=m+1}^\infty E_n\}$ is a finite partition of $E$, and thus 
$$\sum_{n=1}^m|\mu(E_n)|+|\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=m+1}^\infty E_n\right)|\leq \mu_A(E) $$
Since $m$ was arbitrary, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty|\mu(E_n)|\leq\mu_A(E)$$
Taking the supremum over all partitions $\{E_n\}$ of $E$, we see that 
$$|\mu|(E)\leq\mu_A(E).$$

Comment: Sorry about all of the edits, I noticed quite a few typos